GTest cannot be included despite following the primer page
For context, I am using Visual Studio 2022 with:

Test Adapter for Google Test installed from the VS installer
a newly created CMake project from the corresponding project template

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(my_project)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++14
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  hello_test.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
  hello_test
  gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)

hello_test.cpp:
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (errors out here)

I copied CMakeLists.txt straight from the primer page with some changes:

hello_test.cc -> hello_test.cpp
GTest::gtest_main -> gtest_main

While the CMake cache generates, I still can't include <gtest/gtest.h> in hello_test.cpp. It likely isn't intellisense screwing me over since the program just straight up doesn't want to build. I'm happy to share more error information if requested.
What should I do to get GTest to work on my project?

"GTest::gtest_main -> gtest_main" - Despite of given change is unlikely the reason of your problem, it is better to use "namespaced" googletest targets. 1. That way you project would work not only with downloaded Googletest, but also with the installed one (which is included via find_package(GTest). 2. Would Googletest change their targets names, and GTest::gtest_main won't refer to a target, CMake will complain about that. But would gtest_main won't refer to a target, CMake wll silently ignore that fact.

@Tsyvarev I made the change since it made the following error: Target "hello_test" links to: GTest::gtest_main but the target was not found. . Changing it back to GTest::gtest_main and adding find_package(GTest) earlier on yielded the same error. Thanks for the tip though!

I just followed the steps in the Quickstart: Building with CMake and it worked well for me. What is the reason why you change target_link_libraries()? Try again from a new empty directory. When you get success, try hello_test.cc -> hello_test.cpp. Don't change target_link_libraries().

Weird. It smells like GTest is not included into your project at all, neither with FetchContent_Declare nor with find_package. BTW, what do you mean by "Test Adapter for Google Test installed from the VS installer"? With the code in the question post, you use Google Test downloaded from the repository, not the pre-installed one. Unless.. unless Visual Studio actually provides you some other Google Test installation, which expose its own interface, and which suppresses FetchContent_Declare and find_package.

What if you change the name googletest used in FetchContent_Declare and FetchContent_MakeAvailable to some other name (e.g., gt)? And use GTest::gtest_main.

@273K I've changed it since GTest::gtest_main didn't work at first. I also attempted that, but hello_test.cc didn't work in the first place.

@Tsyvarev unfortunately, no luck in changing the name as well.
